# getting to know classes in C++ better

Tags: c++, class

I have taken several classes now in C++ and a little bit of python. And a common thing that keeps coming up is my failure to really understand whats going on when you are creating a class. I was wondering if someone could either explain the specifics as far as classes in C++ are concerned or least point me to websites that go into great detail. I know the declaration but as far as what is going on with accessors, methods, constructors and destructors and even if you'd like to go as far as define when and why would the best time to use a class. I just need overall clarification. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In programming, you have data and functions that manipulate that data. A structure (`struct`) allows you to group related pieces of data into one logical object.

A class allows you to group data and functions together as a single unit. Thus, instead of saying `matrix_add(m1, m2)`, you can say `m1.add(m2)`. The data and functions can be `private` (only accessible to the class), `protected` (accessible to the class and its children) or `public` (accessible to anyone). This is called **encapsulation**: typically, the data is private and is accessible via a set of public functions. In C++, a `struct` defaults to public scope and a `class` to private scope, but are otherwise identical.

An *accessor* is the name of a function that typically provides acccess to the private data of a class. These can be *getters* that return (or get) the data, or *setters* that modify (or set) the data. Typically, these methods check the input for validity to ensure internal constraints hold. Note that an accessor may not directly return private data, but derived properties; that is, `size` and `empty` on C++ containers (vector, list, ...) could be thought of as accessors even though these could be computed values.

A *constructor* is a special function that allows the class to initialize the data to sane values, or allow the user to create a new object of the class with potentially different data. For example, a rectangle class could be constructed from another rectangle, a point and size, a set of top/left/bottom/right values or could be empty. In C++, the constructor has the same name as the class; in python this is called `__init__`.

A *default constructor* is a constructor that takes no parameters and initializes the class to its default state (e.g. an identity matrix for a matrix class).

A *copy constructor* is a constructor that takes another object of the class type and creates a copy of it. This allows allocated memory to be handled properly (e.g. for string and vector classes). With a simple data structure the objects are copied by value, so the two objects would reference the same memory.

A *destructor* is a special function that allows the class to perform cleanup. This could be things like deleting any allocated memory, releasing locks on mutexes or closing open file handles. In C++, a destructor has the same name as the class but with a `~` in front of it, e.g. for a `matrix` class the destructor would be `~matrix`.

A *method* is just a function that is a part of a class. Each method takes the class object being operated on as the first parameter. When declaring methods, C++ does this internally for you (providing an implicit `this` argument) while python requires you to provide the parameter explicitly.

In C++, an *operator* is a special function that is used to implement e.g. `+`, `-`, `*` and `/`. This allows you to create classes that can be used like built in types (esp. for mathematical classes like vectors, matrices, complex and rational numbers).

A class (the "derived" class) can inherit from another class (the "base" class). Here, the derived class is a child of the base class and can access any `protected` data or methods. This is called **inheritance**. These form a class *heirarchy*.

A class can be constructed to have `virtual` methods that can be overriden by derived classes. This is called **polymorphism**.

You can declare virtual methods that do not provide any implementation. These methods are called *pure virtual* methods and the classes that provide them are known as *abstract base classes*. Here, the derived class needs to implement these methods, while with non-pure virtual methods the derived class does not need to implement the method.

A class that only has pure virtual methods (no other methods) is effectively an *interface* class. C++ does not have any special notation for this, whereas other languages do.

Interfaces are typically used to interact between two or more different systems. For example, a music player could provide a plugin architecture that allows plugins to extend the supported audio formats it can handle. Here, the interface(s) provide the contract between the player and plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Think of objects as "smart" structures which not just contain data but also the code to manipulate that data. Think of classes as type definitions for these "smart" structures.

Creating a class instance is just like creating a variable of a structure type. Calling a member function of a class is just like calling a normal function, and passing the structure to it as a parameter with the name "this".

When you understood this, you already understand most about what object-oriented programming is all about.

By the way: Do you know what's the difference between the keywords `struct` and `class` in C++?  In a struct, all members are public by default and in a class all members are private by default. That's it. Otherwise structs and classes are the same thing. When you explicitely declare all members as private, public or protected, you can switch them out and the program will compile and work just like before.

Comment: I'm sure OOP methodologists would disagree with most of what you say, and begin to babble about interfaces, encapsulation and other confusing stuff. In the view of C++, you are of course right: objects are **data**. Methods are **functions** which operate on the data.

Answer (score 1):

> And a common thing that keeps coming up is my failure to really understand whats going on when you are creating a class.

I'm answering this part as others have answered the second part, code below is java however, looking at the code kindly give importance to class concept than Java constructs.

Well, before jumping into the CLASS thing in the programming world. Lets take a look a the real world. If we look around us we see many elements [rocks, animals, humans, plants etc]  in our living echo system. Careful observation finds that, they have some common features that can be grouped together [Life, Organs, Color etc] , lets call this common grouping by a technical name called "CLASS".

In order to understand, classes in programming world one should understand why there is such a construct called class. Main fact is the it is part of a programming paradigm called Object Oriented Programming, where, programmers try to map real world objects say Vehicles, Banks, etc into programming models called Objects. In order to create these object, we have to create a construct that can actually describe those objects. Such a construct is called a class.

Below explanations goes beyond just Classes for completeness.

Lets look at a technical example Circle, Rectangle, Square, Hexagon, looking at them we find that they belong to a common CLASS called SHAPE.

Don't get carried away by details [extends, @Override etc] in the example below. It explains simple concept of classing how it is exploited to make new classes. Once a class is created, it is just a skeleton ie it is not allocated any memory for a real use. In order to make a class useful, we create its objects. So objects are 'elements' with different states for same class.

Say for circle objects, obj1, obj2, each object have different radius.

```
class Shape {

    String name;
    int color;

    public Shape(String name, int color) {
        this.name = name;
        this.color = color; 
    }

    String getName() {
        return name;    
    }

    int getColor() {
        return color;   
    }

    double getArea() {
        return 0;   
    }

    double getPerimeter() {
        return 0;
    }

}

class Rectangle extends Shape {

    int l, b;

    public Rectangle(int l, int b, int h, int color) {  
        super("Rectangle", color);  
        this.l = l;
        this.b = b;
    }

    /* Overloading */   
    @Override 
    double getArea() {
        return l*b; 
    }
    /* Overloading */
    @Override
    double getPerimeter() {
        return (2*l + 2*b);
    }
}

class Circle extends Shape {

    int r;

    public Circle(int r, int color) {
        super("Circle", color);
        this.r = r;
    }   

    dobule getArea() {
        return (PI * (r*r));    
    }

    double getPerimeter() {
        return (2*PI*r);
    }
}
```

Comment: NOTE: The code in your example is Java, not C++ or Python (to avoid confusing `foolprogrammer` who posted the question).

Comment: I do agree, i should have given a C++ example. I believe i have edited it accordingly.